# Android Contextual Action Bar - Select all / Deselect all

Tags: android, android-menu

I'm looking for a way to implement a drop down on a contextual action bar, that shows the number of items selected, then has a drop down for either Select all or Deselect all. The standard Gallery app has this.

Is the only way to do it, to create a custom view to replace the title, or is there a simpler way? If you need to call

> setCustomView

and replace the title, what's the best way of doing this. Would a Popup Menu be suitable. I want it to follow the same style as the contextual action bar for things like touch feedback, colours and the small arrow indicating their are more options.

Thanks.